# No video when using spark VideoPlayer AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am using this code but I am getting only audio and no video .. it is an FLV file and working correctly on other players.

```
<s:VideoPlayer id="vidPl"
                   source="com\gcs\quest\assets\videos\TheUltimateFailsCompilation.flv"
                   skinClass="skins.CustomVideoPlayerSkin"
                   autoPlay="true"
                   muted="false"
                   horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />
```

Comment: "Assuming" the video frame is 'black': If so, make sure that your render mode is set to `direct`

Comment: there is attribute called renderingMode takes normal or cff .. tried both and still no video just hearing audio

Comment: See my answer, render mode is a Flash/Air "RUNTIME" level parameter..

Comment: @MoayadAhmad I think that your video is not a valid FLV video file, try to verify the video format or try another FLV file, you can also upload your video to verify it with you ...

Comment: @SushiHangover I don't think that `renderMode` or `wmode` has something to do with this problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Black video frame but audio is playing fine:

You did not say if this is running via browser-based Flash or desktop/mobile Air, so for anything using stage video:

- HTML: in the object tag, add the parameter `<param value='direct' name='mode'>`
- HTML: in the embed tag, add the attribute `wmode='direct'`
- AIR: change the render mode: `<renderMode>direct</renderMode>`

Ref: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

Ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html

Comment: For anyone who comes across this in the future, this did NOT help me. However, the solution from here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33896 did. Add OSMFSettings.enableStageVideo = false;